# remove 1 region when click button in react-wavesurfer

Tags: reactjs, region, wavesurfer.js

In react-wavesurfer, how the click region is playing from start to finish of that region.
and how do I remove a region when I click a button?

thank help!

Comment: Welcome to SO, it would be really helpful if you can provide an code example that people that can hand on.  An example (pics/links) of what you want to achieve want also be useful.

Comment: Hi, is your question about **react** developpement, web, front-end and javascript ? If yes, you need to give more information so we can help you. Else, maybe, here is not the place where you should post your question.